# Will an implicit variable in a using clause be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

In the following code, does the underlying code contain a hard reference to the unnamed variable instance of type Foo, or is the item vulnerable to garbage collection?

```
using(new Foo())
{
    // Something done here.
}
```

The collected item is just a semaphore type object that performs some reference counting on resources so it isn't being referenced in the code block.

Comment: The `using` block disposes the object at the end of the block.  Ergo, there must be a reference for it to dispose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `using` clause creates a hidden locally-scoped variable holding the object (this variable is used by the generated `finally` clause).

This variable prevents the object from being GC'd.

You can [see this variable in the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

```
using(new Foo())
```

this anonymous instance of `Foo` will go out of scope **after** the using block and may be garbage collected then.